# Rename multiple files via shell script

Tags: shell-script, rename

I want to rename the following files
0 , 0.001 ,0.002 , 0.003 ... , 0.035

into  0 , 1 , 2  , 3 ... , 35

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` solution (provided extglob shell option is enabled - see [pattern matching manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html))

```
for i in 0.* ; do mv "$i" "${i##0.*(0)}" ; done
```

- `${i##` delete longest match from beginning of `i` variable
- `0.` matches the character sequence `0.`
- `*(0)` means zero or more occurrences of 0

or this solution suggested by @Costas, which doesn't need the *extglob* option

```
for i in 0.* ; do mv "$i" "${i#${i%%[!0.]*}}" ; done
```

- `${i%%` delete longest match from end of `i` variable
- `*` any character, zero or more times
- `[!0.]` characters other than `0.`
- so, `${i%%[!0.]*}` effectively deletes from first non `0` or `.` character till end. For ex: `35` gets deleted for `0.035`, `1` for `0.001`, `str0.00456a` for `0str0.00456a` and entire string for `str0.00456a`
- the remaining characters (ex: `0.0` for `0.035` and `0.00` for `0.001` gets passed to `${i#` which then deletes these characters from beginning of variable, resulting in `35` for `0.035` and `1` for `0.001`

Further reading: [Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

Comment: Or `${i#${i%%[!0.]*}}` if you have not *extglob* option

Comment: For pattern match it is not fully true explanation: `*` means `any symbol(s) in any quantity (include nothing)`, `%%[!0.]` means `*leftmost* symbol other than "0" and "."`

Comment: @Costas, thanks for explanation.. I've updated the answer, can you see if it is okay?

Comment: Yes, it is OK now

Comment: Thank you very much , works perfectly but I have another problem.

Comment: These files extracted from OpenFOAM so after 0.009, file 0.01 is extracted. So with this code 0.01 will be 1 after rename and will replace file 1 (i.e. 0.001 from previous rename). Oops!

Comment: @KonstantinosGiannokostas am not entirely sure from your comment if this solution is okay or not okay.. I take it as that you have another problem not entirely addressed in this Q&A, if so feel free to ask another question

Answer (score 1):

With `rename` (`prename`):

```
rename -n 's/^[^.]+\.0*([1-9]+)$/$1/' 0*
```

`-n` will do the dry-run, if you are satisfied with the changes to be made, do:

```
rename 's/^[^.]+\.0*([1-9]+)$/$1/' 0*
```

**Example:**

```
% rename -n 's/^[^.]+\.0*([1-9]+)$/$1/' 0*
0.001 renamed as 1
0.002 renamed as 2
0.003 renamed as 3
0.035 renamed as 35
```

Comment: or just `rename -n 's/0\.0*//' 0*` ?

Comment: @spasic We need to be sure that we have digits at last, OP has not clarified that otherwise your one is correct too..

Comment: oh ok :) .. from question, I feel OP has exactly those 36 files